# Logging out from another computer

Tags: facebook, authentication

I left my Facebook page up at work. Can I log out of it from my home computer so no one can mess with my page?

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to **Account Settings**
   [image]
2. In the left side menu, go to **Security**
   [image]
3. Click on **Edit** on the *Active Sessions* category (last from the bottom)
   [image]
4. Click on **End Activity** for the session you want to close
   [image]

Comment: Nice. Could be easy/useful to monitor.